# Infinispan - Can I create DefaultCacheManager for each web application in the server

Tags: caching, jboss, wildfly, infinispan

I do not understand the following statement of DefaultCacheManager's [Java doc](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/9.4/apidocs/org/infinispan/manager/DefaultCacheManager.html). It says

> CacheManagers are heavyweight objects, and we foresee no more than one CacheManager being used per JVM

- Am I allowed to create DefaultCacheManager programmatically for each web application in the server? For example, I have two web applications, A and B. They are running in the JBoss AS (standalone only). Each web application (A and B) creates own DefaultCacheManager object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create more cache managers. The term *heavyweight* here means that cache manager contains thread pools, JGroups channels (that means consumed ports) etc. so you should not create too many of these.

The situation might be a bit different in an application server with deep integration - some of the resources can be shared there. Check out the Infinispan subsystem - cache manager then maps to a `cache-container`. It's perfectly fine to have multiple cache containers in the configuration.

In application server, the applications should not *create* the cache managers; these should be only injected (e.g. through CDI) to your webapp.